# How to move OCI-classic to OCI

Tags: oracle, cloud

I have been using OCI-classic. And I'd like to move OCI-classic to OCI.
So I'd be greatly appreciated if you could tell me about below.

1. Support limitation of OCI-classic
2. Sample of migration from OCI-classic to OCI

If you can do, tell me the URL too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different migration tools responsible for this, but at the same time, there are considerations you should make before migration to OCI, what kind of services you will migrate, compute,storage, and other services. It would help if you mapped before doing anything.

I highly recommended reading this documentation from Oracle to take a brief about the migration **[here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas-classic/compute-iaas-cloud/migrate-oci/migrate-vms-and-block-storage.html#GUID-7099C387-9826-4D22-A448-C3FC4ABBD094)**

Comment: Thank you for giving me your advice.
At first, I'd like to read the document you teach me.
I'd like to be taken advises when finishing to read and not clearly the point that I can't realize.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OCI-classic is a single tenant offering from Oracle Cloud with limited support. With the multitenant cloud premise available on OCI, it is best to move to OCI . There are lots of interconnected services on OCI which can help lift and shift but it also needs oracle devops help. I would suggest to reach out to Oracle support using SR and they can guide further based on your environment.